# SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A while creating object for gmail

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, gmail

I am using GMail gem for read and send mail functions, but it throws the following error:

**Code:**

```
require "gmail" 
gmail_instance = Gmail.new(email,password)
```

**Error**:

```
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1454:in `connect'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1454:in `start_tls_session'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1047:in `initialize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail/client/base.rb:26:in `new'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail/client/base.rb:26:in `connect'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gmail-0.4.0/lib/gmail.rb:49:in `new'
```